# Returning a class object by reference inside another class

Tags: c++, oop, reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
   class A {
     public:

      int getX() { return x; }
      private:
       int x;
};

    class B {
        public:
              A& getA () {return a;}
         private:
              A a;
     };

     int main() {
       B* b = new B;
       if(b) { 
           b->getA().setX(10);
           printf("\n Value is %p",&(b->getA()));
           b->getA().setX(5);
       }
       return 0;
     }
```

In the above code is there any problem and is there any case where getA() can return a NULL pointer or invalid pointer . If yes what is valid check for it ?

Comment: You are mixing C and C++, use `iostream` and `cout` instead of `stdio` and `printf`

Comment: The null check is on the result of `new B`. Which would not return null but throw an exception unless you were using a very old compiler.

Comment: references can never be null (unless your program already caused undefined behaviour of course)

Comment: `if(b)` is redundant and should be removed, `new` will either succeed or throw. If you don't want to throw, write `new(std::nothrow) B;` and retain the null check. Of course `B b;` is simpler

Comment: Even in C++, the requirement for the argument corresponding to `%p` is that it be a `void *`. You could say this is just nitpicking, and it kind of is, but if the only person who could help you used some ancient compiler on some ancient system, they'd probably stop helping you when you argue with them about how this isn't undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reference **cannot** be null. Testing or checking for null is redundant. Your compiler already does that. It will only confuse people who know the language.

*(obviously this is C++, you can put any value into any memory location, but checking references for null is not going to help you if someone else is manipulating your memory.)*

Comment: I have not seen compilers catching null dereferences, but the OS generally does.

Comment: Well your compiler *should* not allow you to leave a reference uninitialized or a nullptr. That's what I meant. If you want to get a nullptr into a reference, that's a lot of hard work to trick your compiler into allowing it.

Comment: Clang at least [lets me sail right into UB land](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b58290d888892b5b), even in the trivial case. Am I missing the point ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really check if references are valid or not (also they cannot be null). So when you use references keep that in mind that you make sure as long as you use them the object stays valid (e.g. as function parameters).

Returning Objects by reference can be helpful performance wise, but you can introduce bugs when e.g. you `B` object gets destroyed and you have saved this `A&`.

So if possible avoid returning references (except when you can make sure the object it references never gets invalid e.g. global variables) and if you have to be careful with them. They can introduce hard to find bugs.